# Destructure Spread off Import ES6

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

```
import {Component, ...actions} from '../MyModule';
```

Seems to be throwing a linting error. Is there a reason why you can't "spread" on an ES6 import statement?

Comment: What do you expect the destructuring to do? Give you all other exports minus `Component`?

Comment: Have a look at the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports the notation for _NamedImports_ may look like object notation but it is something different (that is why there is no destructuring). If  _MyModule_ exports an object you could do the destructuring in an assignment.

Comment: Mostly because spread operators are not part of ES6, but a proposal for some future version.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

ES6 import syntax is not destructuring, it's as simple as that. The syntax starts with `{`, but its format is entirely different, and the way that it is handled in the implementation is quite different. For instance, you can rename imports with

```
 import {Component as MyComponent} from './MyModule';
```

which is clearly not an object literal.

If you need an object that you can use to reference imports as properties, you could do

```
 import * as MyModule from '../MyModule';
```

then use `MyModule.<exportName>`. If you objective is specifically to get an object that contains all of the export values, excluding `Component` then you could always do destructuring after, e.g.

```
 const {Component, ...actions} = MyModule;
```