# Deconstructing with rest operator on import

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose I have a module like this with a bunch of exports.

```js
// my-module.ts

export function foo() { ... }

export function bar() { ... }

export function foobar() { ... }

export function barfoo() { ... }
```

Why can't I just deconstruct with the rest operator on import?

```js
// no-work.ts

import { foo, ...others } from './my-module'
```

While the next code works, is there any work around besides that?

```js
// works.ts

import * as _others from './my-module'

const { foo, ...others } = _others
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Destructure Spread off Import ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862325/destructure-spread-off-import-es6)

Comment: If you add `export default { foo, bar, foobar, barfoo }` to "my-module.ts", you could import with: `import rest, { foo } from "./my-module";`. If I'm not mistaken...